# Applying a vectorized function to a list by un-listing, then re-listing

Tags: r, list, vectorization

Suppose you have a list of character vectors:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- lapply(sample(10:50), function(x) {
  sapply(1:x, function(y) {
    paste(sapply(y, sample, x=letters, size=sample(5:10, 1)), collapse='')
  })
})
```

You would like to apply a vectorized operation across this entire list.  One option is to  `unlist(x)`, and then apply the vectorized function:

```
y <- nchar(unlist(x))
```

What is the most efficient way to get `y` back into the same list structure as `x`?  Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative would be to use the `as.relistable` and `relist` functions like this:

```
y <- as.relistable(x)
z <- nchar( unlist(x) )
z <- relist(z,y)
str(head(z))
#List of 6
# $ : int [1:47] 7 8 6 6 6 5 8 10 10 5 ...
# $ : int [1:50] 7 9 9 6 7 10 7 6 10 8 ...
# $ : int [1:21] 8 7 9 5 9 10 5 5 8 9 ...
# $ : int [1:41] 5 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 10 9 ...
# $ : int [1:33] 9 5 9 9 8 9 7 9 6 10 ...
# $ : int [1:28] 5 5 5 9 8 8 8 6 9 6 ...
```

Comment: +1 I think this is what the OP was looking for. I didn't know about this function, I was used to use `lapply(sapply(x, length), function(i) y[seq_len(i)])`

Comment: @dickoa yes I don't often use them because I usually find it convenient to just use an `*apply` function but I guess `relistable` has its uses.

Comment: I realised that my code was not working as intended because of some bad index choice.. anyway thank's for this. It's so cool to learn new trick in R

Comment: I did not know of the `relist` function.  Thank you!  It seems like I learn a new R function every day.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having difficulty understanding why `lapply` is not the answer (and also why Josh deleted his answer that said exactly that 6 hours ago.)

```
charcounts <- lapply(x, nchar )
str(head(charcounts))
List of 6
 $ : int [1:47] 7 8 6 6 6 5 8 10 10 5 ...
 $ : int [1:50] 7 9 9 6 7 10 7 6 10 8 ...
 $ : int [1:21] 8 7 9 5 9 10 5 5 8 9 ...
 $ : int [1:41] 5 9 9 9 5 5 5 5 10 9 ...
 $ : int [1:33] 9 5 9 9 8 9 7 9 6 10 ...
 $ : int [1:28] 5 5 5 9 8 8 8 6 9 6 ...
```

Comment: Hi DWin: I like relist better than lapply in this situation, because in many cases its much faster to unlist, apply a vectorized function, and relist, than to lapply that same function over the list.